# how to place a gridview inside the html table

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, gridview

i am doing something like

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td width="15%" height="50"> Some content </td>
   <td width="25%" height="50"> My dropdown 1 </td>
   <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
       <asp:gridview id="mygrid-1" runat="server">....<asp:gridview>
       <br>
     <asp:gridview id="mygrid-2" runat="server">....<asp:gridview>
   </td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td width="15%" height="50"> Some content </td>
     <td width="25%" height="50"> My dropdown 2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="*">  </td>
</table>
```

On My dropdowns Selexted index change, both grids are populated , but this thing totally ignoring the height i have assigned to my 1st two tables rows , i want 1st two row height to be same as 50 , and on grid data population , i want 3rd row of table to grow in height

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to maintain your row height here, but without seeing more I can't tell what the problem truly is. The first thing coming to mind when looking at your code here is that the width/height properties should really be done in CSS rather than in the html. Then, using CSS for those rows you could further maintain height using `white-space:nowrap;`depending on what that content is.

I'm not positive from looking here, but it seems you may be using your table for layout. Switch to using CSS for layout and turn those rows into `<div>`s and you can work with your gridview in a much more elegant and semantic way.